Does linearity on all commutative subalgebras imply linearity on the whole algebra?
Let $\mathfrak A$ be a $C^\ast$-algebra and $\phi\colon\mathfrak A\to\mathbb C$ a continuous positive function whose restriction to any commutative sub-$C^\ast$-algebra is linear.  Is $\phi$ linear on the whole of $\mathfrak A$?
If not, what if $\phi(\lambda a)=\lambda\phi(a)$ and $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ whenever $a$ and $b$ commute? Note the previous weaker hypotheses apply only to normal commuting $a$ and $b$.
With the stronger hypotheses, we can suppose $a$, $b$, and $a+b$ invertible: for some $\lambda\ge0$ the operators $a+\lambda$, $b+\lambda$, and $a+b+2\lambda$ are all invertible, and $\lambda$ commutes with all of them.
More than this I have not managed to find. The nicest would be some kind of polarisation identity, for instance a polynomial in $a$, $b$, $a^\ast$, and $b^\ast$ which commutes with $a$ and $b$.

What is the definition of a "C-algebra"? Do you mean a $C^*$-algebra?

@krm2233 MSE routinely regards the use of asterisks as indicating texts in italics rather than actual asterisk symbols, which is what happened as can be seen in the underlying code of the OP's question. I just fixed it.

@DavidGao Thanks! I'll remember that in future :)

For the first question, the answer is obviously no, as you can define $\phi$ however you want on non-normal elements. They never belong to any commutative $C^\ast$-subalgebra, nor are they ever positive.

Here is a counterexample for the second question. In fact, I'll show that when $A = M_2(\mathbb{C})$, there is a positive non-linear $\phi: A \to \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $\phi$ is linear on all maximal abelian subalgebras of $A$ (without assuming the subalgebra in question is self-adjoint). This is clearly enough to yield a counterexample.
We first need to consider what is the structure of a maximal abelian subalgebra $B$ of $A$. Clearly, $\mathbb{C} \subsetneq B$. Thus, we may pick a non-scalar $T \in B$. By considering the Jordan normal form of $T$, we have, after changing bases, either,
$$T = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix}$$
for some $\alpha \neq \beta$. Let $S = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$. Then $[T, S] = 0$ iff,
$$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha a & \alpha b \\ \beta c & \beta d \end{pmatrix} = TS = ST = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha a & \beta b \\ \alpha c & \beta d \end{pmatrix}$$
As $\alpha \neq \beta$, this happens iff $b = c = 0$. That is, the commutant of $T$ consists precisely of diagonal matrices, which form an abelian algebra. As $B$ is maximal abelian, $B$ must be the algebra of diagonal matrices. To put it another way, $B = \mathbb{C}p \oplus \mathbb{C}(1 - p)$ for some not necessarily self-adjoint rank-one idempotent $p$.
Or,
$$T = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 1 \\ 0 & \alpha \end{pmatrix}$$
Let $S = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$. Then $[T, S] = 0$ iff $[e_{12}, S] = [T - \alpha, S] = 0$ iff,
$$de_{12} + ce_{11} = e_{12}S = Se_{12} = ae_{12} + ce_{22}$$
This happens iff $a = d$ and $c = 0$, iff $S = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$. It is straightforward to check all such $S$ form an abelian algebra. Again, as $B$ is maximal abelian, $B$ must consist of all such $S$. To put it another way, $B = \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}x$ for some nonzero nilpotent $x$ (in this case, simply $x \neq 0$ and $x^2 = 0$).
Now, using Zorn's lemma, we may choose a maximal set $P$ of (not necessarily self-adjoint) rank-one idempotents s.t. whenever $p \in P$, we have $1 - p \notin P$. By maximality of $P$, we easily see that for each rank-one idempotent $p$, we have either $p \in P$ or $1 - p \in P$, and exactly one of the above holds. We now define $\phi$ by,
$$\phi(ap + b(1 - p)) = a$$
when $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $p \in P$, and,
$$\phi(a + bx) = a$$
when $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x$ is nilpotent. By Jordan normal form decomposition, we see that these two cases cover all possible elements of $A$. We observe that $\phi$ is well-defined. Indeed, if,
$$ap + b(1 - p) = c + dx$$
for some $p \in P$ and nonzero nilpotent $x$. As the LHS is a matrix whose eigenspaces span the entire $\mathbb{C}^2$, the RHS must satisfy the same condition, so by uniqueness of Jordan decomposition, we must have $d = 0$. But then $ap + b(1 - p) = b + (a - b)p = c$, so $a = b = c$ and both definitions of $\phi$ yield the same result.
If,
$$a + bx = c + dy$$
for some nonzero nilpotents $x, y$. Then the LHS has unique eigenvalue $a$, while the RHS has unique eigenvalue $c$. Thus, $a = c$ and the definition of $\phi$ yields a unique result.
Finally, if,
$$ap + b(1 - p) = cq + d(1 - q)$$
for some distinct $p, q \in P$. Then by definition of $P$ we must have $q \neq p, 1 - p$. Again, by uniqueness of Jordan decomposition, we must have $a = b = c = d$, so again the definition of $\phi$ yields a unique result.
Now, we check that $\phi$ is linear on all maximal abelian subalgebras. This is nearly just the definition: Let $B \subset A$ be maximally abelian. Then as we have seen, either $B = \mathbb{C}p \oplus \mathbb{C}(1 - p)$ for some $p \in P$, in which case,
$$\phi(ap + b(1 - p)) = a$$
is clearly linear on $B$, or $B = \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}x$ for some nonzero nilpotent $x$, in which case,
$$\phi(a + bx) = a$$
is also clearly linear on $B$. But $\phi$ is not linear on the entirety of $A$. Indeed, both $e_{12}$ and $e_{21}$ are nonzero nilpotents, so $\phi(e_{12}) = \phi(e_{21}) = 0$, but $e_{12} + e_{21}$ has distinct eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, so $e_{12} + e_{21} = p - (1 - p)$ for some rank-one idempotent $p$. Either $p \in P$ or $1 - p \in P$, so,
$$\phi(e_{12} + e_{21}) = \phi(p - (1 - p)) = 1 \text{ or } -1$$
Either way, $\phi(e_{12} + e_{21}) \neq 0 = \phi(e_{12}) + \phi(e_{21})$, so $\phi$ is not linear.
Finally, we check that $\phi$ is positive. For any $T \in A$ positive, we have $T = \alpha p + \beta (1 - p)$ for some rank-one idempotent $p$ and $\alpha, \beta \geq 0$. Again, either $p \in P$ or $1 - p \in P$, so $\phi(T)$ is either $\alpha$ or $\beta$. In both cases, we have $\phi(T) \geq 0$.

If $\phi$ also satisfies $\phi(a_1+ia_2)=\phi(a_1)+i\phi(a_2)$ ($a_i\in A_{sa}$) then it is said to be a quasilinear functional. Here and here you can find some positive answers for linearity of bounded quasi-linear functionals. Also here a map $\phi:A_{sa}\to B_{sa}$ that is homogeneous and such that $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ whenever $ab=ba$ is called piecewise linear.
